# Having Trouble with AdMob

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I am trying to put **AdMob** in my android application following the instructions given on [android developer website](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)
, but I keep getting the error in my `MainActivity.java`

> AdView.loadAd() error cant resolve the symbol loadAd

Comment: have you added to your sdk : "Google Repository",

Comment: Please, specify your minSdk version. And also add some code where this error appear.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

By `AdView`, I assume you are not referring to the variable.

When you define a new `AdView` object, you do so in a way such as the following:

```
AdView mAdView;
```

This means that `mAdView` is the name of this object and so you call the method with this name. I understand that doesn't sound very clear, but I'll show you what I mean:

```
// Your new AdView is being cast to the view in your XML, and it is called 'mAdView'
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

// You are creating a new AdRequest here
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// Finally, you load the ad (using mAdView as the name, and adRequest as your parameter)
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Make sure your code looks like the above, but to summarise, you need to call your `loadAd()` using the name of your `AdView` object, for example, `mAdView`.